# Can I filter Google Analytics reports for visitors who saw a certain page?

Tags: google-analytics

e.g., In looking at ecommerce stats for a custom variables report, I only want to see numbers for visitors who visited our shipping rates page (zip_check.php).

I don't see anything in "advanced segments" that will help.

I've also tried "filters" in "custom reporting". The most hopeful filter fields I saw were "Page" and "Page Title", but it's unclear to me what these filter do. They don't appear to simply filter for sessions or visits that contain a visit to a particular page.

Here's a [report snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igPgS.jpg) after applying a "Page Title" filter. The numbers obviously got wacky.

UPDATE:
Here's a [complete snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TSXc.jpg) of the report after using "Customize" to filter for "Page Title" exact= "Shipping Calculator".

Comment: Could you snapshot the whole report? Generally you can do this with a simple saved search/include/exclude based on the page URL.

Comment: @toomanyairmiles I think I understand what you requested, and I updated the question with a link to a screenshot of the whole report. Is this what you had in mind?

Answer (score 2):

the best way to approach this would be through advanced segments; selecting 'page' and entering the URL of the page you want to restrict visits for. Filters are not applied retrospectively to the data whereas advanced segments are.